# Function, return last object thats value(s) are equal to something. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, break

I want a function which checks for each object in an array if a value is the same as in the object.

But I don't want to return all objects where this is true, and also not the first, I want to return only the last object where `name = array[i].name`.

```js
var allInfo = [
  {name: "Olaf", lastname: "Kranz", age:33},
  {name: "Mark", lastname: "Alien", age:21},
  {name: "Cindy", lastname: "Sunsi", age:65},
  {name: "Anna", lastname: "Pitter", age:20},
  {name: "Piet", lastname: "Schmitz", age:29}
];

var name = 'Cindy';
document.write(getIfNameIsAvailable(name));


function getIfNameIsAvailable(name) {
  for (i = allInfo.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (allInfo[i].name == name) {
      return allInfo[i].lastname;
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I think your function is good, you just need to start from `allInfo.length - 1`, not `allInfo.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three issues:

1. Array indexes are `length - 1` through `0`, not `length` through `0`, which is why your code throws an error on the first exection.
2. You don't need `break` after `return`, since `return` exits the function (and thus the loop as well).
3. You **do** need to declare your variables, including loop counters like `i`. If you don't, you get what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

With the `- 1`, removing `break`, and declaring `i` — I also changed Mark Allen's name to Cindy so we could see it really is grabbing the last Cindy:

```js
var allInfo = [
  {name: "Olaf", lastname: "Kranz", age:33},
  {name: "Cindy", lastname: "Alien", age:21},
  {name: "Cindy", lastname: "Sunsi", age:65},
  {name: "Anna", lastname: "Pitter", age:20},
  {name: "Piet", lastname: "Schmitz", age:29}
];

var name = 'Cindy';
document.write(getIfNameIsAvailable(name));

function getIfNameIsAvailable(name) {
  for (var i = allInfo.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (allInfo[i].name == name) {
      return allInfo[i].lastname;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, @T.J Crowder (Legend) has already given you the reason why you were facing the issue. I would just like to let you know another way of doing it. So you may not have to face these kinds of issues. Try embracing `JS` ready made utilities. [**`.find`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for example.  One line of code an you are done

```
allInfo.find(o=> o.name === name)
```

```js
var allInfo = [
  {name: "Olaf", lastname: "Kranz", age:33},
  {name: "Mark", lastname: "Alien", age:21},
  {name: "Cindy", lastname: "Sunsi", age:65},
  {name: "Anna", lastname: "Pitter", age:20},
  {name: "Piet", lastname: "Schmitz", age:29}
];

var name = 'Cindy';
document.write(getIfNameIsAvailable(name));


function getIfNameIsAvailable(name) {
  return allInfo.find(o=> o.name === name).lastname
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let allInfo = [
  {name: "Olaf", lastname: "Kranz", age:33},
  {name: "Mark", lastname: "Alien", age:21},
  {name: "Cindy", lastname: "Sunsi", age:65},
  {name: "Anna", lastname: "Pitter", age:20},
  {name: "Piet", lastname: "Schmitz", age:29},
  {name: "Cindy", lastName: "Surname", age: 22}
];

let getIfNameIsAvailable = (name, arr) => arr.slice(0).reverse().find(item => item.name == name);

let person = getIfNameIsAvailable('Cindy', allInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention a while loop with an index and decrementing after checking.

```js
function getIfNameIsAvailable(name) {
    var i = allInfo.length

    while (i--) {
        if (allInfo[i].name == name) {
            return allInfo[i].lastname;
        }
    }
}

var allInfo = [{ name: "Olaf", lastname: "Kranz", age:33 }, { name: "Mark", lastname: "Alien", age:21 }, { name: "Cindy", lastname: "Sunsi", age:65 }, { name: "Anna", lastname: "Pitter", age:20 }, { name: "Piet", lastname: "Schmitz", age:29 }];

console.log(getIfNameIsAvailable('Cindy'));
```